# track total number items submitted in php

Tags: php, forms, input, count

I'm fairly new to coding with php however I'm trying to learn by making my very own website.

Process:
User fills form -> submits form -> data is saved in db

What I want to do:
Every time a form is submitted, the system should add ' 1 ' to the total number of forms submitted -> a variable ' n '.

If there're any solutions to this it'd be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: If you're saving to a database, you could have an ID field as per Daan that will automatically increment on data being inserted, you may already have this in your table.

Comment: I see. And if I were to set a limit of let's say 100 forms only, I can just add an if function right? or is there any special code for this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah use below code

$totalformcount=mysql_num_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE A"));// return total number of forms

if($totalformcount<=100){
    show form
}else{
   no form limit 100 completed
}